# How can i change my menu to show the active menu

Tags: jquery, css

Can someone tell me in what way I can change the jQuery code in order to get a active tab concept. 
that is: the one which shows which menu is active at a time.

I have included all the HTML , CSS and JS files that i have used.

HTML :

```
<ul class="au-img">enter code here
    <li><a id="andrew" ><img id="aila" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pyconic-icons-1-2/512/grid-layout-project-128.png" alt="this"></a></li>
  <li><a id="john" ><img id="aila1" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/thin-time-date/57/thin-026_time_clock_watch-256.png" alt="thisone"></a></li>
  <li><a id="nate" ><img id="aila2" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cosmo-mobile/40/book-512.png" alt="thisone2"></a></li>
</ul>



<div class="about-andrew hide">
  <h3>GRID</h3>
  <p>THIS IS GRID CLICKED</p>
</div>
<div class="about-john hide">
  <h3>CLOCK</h3>
  <p>THIS IS CLOCK CLICKED</p>
</div>
<div class="about-nate hide">
  <h3>BOOK</h3>
  <p>THIS IS BOOK CLICKED</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin:0;padding:0; }
body { background:#E9EEF5; }

ul {

 background-color:orange;

}

li {

  display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:33.33%;
    background:#E6E6E6;
    min-height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;

}

img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.default-text {
  font:20pt 'Georgia';

  margin:20px auto 0;
  text-align:center;
}

div {
    clear:both;
  position:relative;
  margin:0px auto 0;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;

}

h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
#aila {

    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    padding-top:7px;
}
#aila1 {

    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    padding-top:7px;
}
#aila2 {

    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    padding-top:7px;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.au-img a').on("click", function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
      $id = $this.attr('id'),
      $class = '.' + $('.about-' + $id).attr('class').replace('hide', '');

  $('.default-text').addClass('hide');
  $('.about-' + $id).removeClass('hide');
  $('div[class*=about]').not($class).addClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: Make css class for Active tag and inactive tab.

Comment: @Amy ... Answer is absolutely correct thanks :) 

can you help me to implement it specifically like http://www.cssdrive.com/elements/slideshowpro.gif

Comment: @amy I am sorry, the answer that has been posted that was almost a resolution for my question..

Comment: Raise new question for new query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```js
var flag;
$('.au-img a').on("click", function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
      $id = $this.attr('id'),
      $class = '.' + $('.about-' + $id).attr('class').replace('hide', '');

  $('.default-text').addClass('hide');
  $('.about-' + $id).removeClass('hide');
  $('div[class*=about]').not($class).addClass('hide');
   $(this).parent().css( "background-color", "red" );
  $(flag).parent().css( "background-color", "#E6E6E5" );
 
  flag=this;
  
});
```

```css
* { margin:0;padding:0; }
body { background:#E9EEF5; }

ul {

 background-color:orange;

}

li {

  display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:33.33%;
    background:#E6E6E5;
    min-height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;

}

img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.default-text {
  font:20pt 'Georgia';

  margin:20px auto 0;
  text-align:center;
}

div {
    clear:both;
  position:relative;
  margin:0px auto 0;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;

}

h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
#aila {

    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    padding-top:7px;
}
#aila1 {

    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    padding-top:7px;
}
#aila2 {

    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    padding-top:7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="au-img">
    <li><a id="andrew" ><img id="aila" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pyconic-icons-1-2/512/grid-layout-project-128.png" alt="this"></a></li>
  <li><a id="john" ><img id="aila1" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/thin-time-date/57/thin-026_time_clock_watch-256.png" alt="thisone"></a></li>
  <li><a id="nate" ><img id="aila2" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cosmo-mobile/40/book-512.png" alt="thisone2"></a></li>
</ul>



<div class="about-andrew hide">
  <h3>GRID</h3>
  <p>THIS IS GRID CLICKED</p>
</div>
<div class="about-john hide">
  <h3>CLOCK</h3>
  <p>THIS IS CLOCK CLICKED</p>
</div>
<div class="about-nate hide">
  <h3>BOOK</h3>
  <p>THIS IS BOOK CLICKED</p>
</div>
```